# How can I use my US-iPhone in South Korea?

Tags: iphone

I have an iPhone 4S and I will be going to South Korea for a year for my 1st duty station in the army. What should I do? Can I get it unlocked or should I just by a phone over there? I need contact with my family.

Comment: Which provider are you using in the States?

Comment: AT&T, I've heard about a SIM card I can put in it if I get unlocked?

Answer (score 1):

Before buying a CDMA SIM in Korea, check that your iPhone 4s is

1. a CDMA phone, and
2. unlocked

Calling stateside from South Korea using a Korea-issued SIM card may be expensive. You should consider getting iOS apps (e.g. Skype, WhatsApp) that relies on WiFi or data plan to communicate.

Comment: Well yeah I know but it'll mostly be used for me to text my people here in the US

Answer (score 1):

Call AT&T and have them unlock your phone. You're eligible for this process. Check out [this link](http://www.att.com/esupport/article.jsp?sid=KB414532&cv=820#fbid=kPy--VHLHuq) for more info. You qualify for the normal unlocking procedure, but you may also qualify for the military phone unlock as well. Double up for double power!

Buy a Koren Microsim Card of your choice from a cell service provider.

Use Skype, Facetime, Vyber, Whatsapp, or any of the other apps available on the market to have free international calling/text, as international calls with most providers are prohibitively expensive.

If you have a good data connection, you can send free iMessages to friends who own Apple products internationally.